# I can't fill my inputs when I click the "update" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table and my table has a delete and update button for each person. I want that whichever person's update button is pressed, that person's properties fill the `DropDownList`s.  I've done this before on my other tables, but they were `@Html.TextBoxFor` fields.  I couldn't do the same for `DropDownListFor`. I checked with `console.log` if the data is correct. My data is coming true.

Code I tried:

DropDownListFor:

```
 <label for="repairCustomerInput" class="form-label">Müşteri</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Repairs.musteriID, new SelectList(Model.CustomersList, "musteri_id", "musteriAdSoyad"), "Lütfen bir müşteri seçiniz", 
    new { @class = "form-control repair-inputs", id = "repairCustomerInput", required = "required" })
```

Button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-update" data-id="@item.bakim_id" data-customer="@item.musteriAdSoyad" data-product="@item.urunAd" data-date="@item.alinanTarih" data-month="@item.ay">
    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
</button>
```

Js :

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-update', function () {
    openModal(true);
    $("#repair_id").val($(this).data("id"));
    $("#repairCustomerInput").val($(this).data("customer"));
    $("#repiarProductInput").val($(this).data("product"));
    $("#repairDateInput").val($(this).data("date"));
    $("#repairMonthInput").val($(this).data("month"));
});
```

Comment: I edited your tags to replace the generic [model-view-controller] with the specific ASP.net tag so it'll reach the people who might be able to help.

Comment: Please read these [concise but important guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before asking questions. **"It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough.** What does your code produce? We are not telepaths.